# How to convert Linux date string to Python Datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am trying to convert the Linux date time 'Fri Feb 25 16:07:17 UTC 2022' to python datetime but not able to achieve the same. However, I am able to do using below code, but still looking for the right approach:

Input -> Fri Feb 25 16:07:17 UTC 2022

```
from datetime import datetime
linux_date="Fri Feb 25 16:07:17 UTC 2022"
arr=linux_date.split(' ')
py_str=f"{arr[1]+' '+arr[2]+' '+arr[5]+' '+arr[3]}"
py_str=(datetime.strptime(py_str, '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
py_str
```

Output -> '2022-02-25 16:07:17'

Comment: Answers given are correct, but if you want more information, you can find it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, Yes I was missing this and that was the mistake. @theherk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
linux_date = 'Fri Feb 25 16:07:17 UTC 2022'

import datetime
new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(linux_date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
print(new_date)
```

**Output**

`2022-02-25 16:07:17`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
datetime.strptime(linux_date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

- `%a` abbreviated day of week
- `%b` abbreviated month name
- '%d` day of month
- `%H:%M:%S` - time as hours:minutes:seconds
- `%Z` - timezone name
- `%Y` - 4-digit year